# JavaScript UML Component Diagram Notation

Tags: javascript, uml, component-diagram

It seems that the way to connect entities on UML diagram is with ball-and-socket/lollipop notation. Each ball and socket pair should be listed with the interface implemented. However, as my project is in JavaScript there are no interfaces, so I am confused about what should replace it.

Am I right to use ball and socket notation, or is there some other notation I should use that would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You connect your classes with associations. You can place role names and use the dot-notation to represent properties used to navigate between the classes.

From the specs. pp. 203:

[image]

> ... GH, end h is owned by Class G and end g is owned by Class H. Because the ends are class- owned, they are navigable. This is in a diagram where arrows are only shown for one-way navigable associations.

The lollipop-notation is used primarily to show interfaces between components (though you can also use it for classes).

Comment: Specification document is here for those interested: http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/About-UML/

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use the ball-and-socket/lollipop notation here just like an high level of abstraction on how your components are communicating. In fact here your are modelling your system in a certain abstraction level, so it is not the real one (obviously there must be consistency!).

See for example this [UML Component Diagram Example](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/software-licensing-component-diagram-example.html?context=cmp-examples).